# Reading CSV file and take majority voting of certain column

Tags: python-2.7, csv, counting

I need to calculate the majority vote for an TARGET_LABEL Column of my CSV file in Python.

I have a data frame with Row ID and assigned TARGET_LABEL. What I need is the count of TARGET_LABEL(majority). How do I do this?

For Example Data is in this form:

```
 **Row ID        TARGET_LABEL**
      Row2          0
      Row6          0
      Row7          0
      Row10         0
      Row12         0
      Row15         1
       .            . 
       .            .
      Row99999      1
```

I have python script which only reads data from CSV. Here It is

```
import csv

ifile = open('file1.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

rownum = 0
for row in reader:
# Save header row.
 if rownum == 0:
    header = row
 else:
     colnum = 0
     for col in row:
         print '%-8s: %s' % (header[colnum], col)
         colnum += 1

  rownum += 1

ifile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case TARGET_LABEL** does not have a NaN values, you could use:

```
counts = df['TARGET_LABEL'].value_counts()
max_counts = counts.max()
```

Otherwise if it could contain NaN values, use

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['TARGET_LABEL'])
```

removes all the NaN values

```
df['TARGET_LABEL'].value_counts().max()
```

should give you the max counts,

```
df['TARGET_LABEL'].value_counts().idxmax()
```

should give you the most frequent value.

Comment: what is df? is this a function? I doesn't know that much of python.

Comment: df stands for dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The package `collection` contains the class `Counter` which works similar to a `dict` (or more precisely a `defaultdict(lambda: 0)`) and which can be used to find the most frequent item.